# How to get column ID via #{component.id} in EL?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, el

I just want to send the **Column ID** as a parameter (and I don't want to write it twice, of course).

I used to make use of `component.id` but it returns **DataTable ID** instead of **Column ID**:

```
<p:dataTable id="table_id" ... >
    <p:column id="column_id"  attr="#{bean.method(component.id)}"
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DataTableRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#DataTableRenderer) of PrimeFaces indeed never pushes the `UIColumn` component into EL as `#{component}` when it's about to render the header, cell and footer of a column. It's fortunately relatively easy to override it to do so.

Create a class which extends it and then override the `encodeColumnHeader()`, `encodeCell()` and `encodeColumnFooter()` to first [push](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent)) the given `Column` component (you need to downcast the `UIColumn` argument first; you may want to perform an instanceof check if you're also using the "dynamic columns" feature) before delegating to `super`. Don't forget to [pop](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#popComponentFromEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) in `finally` to ensure that EL don't get polluted with wrong `#{component}` state in case of an exception.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q25464066;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn;
import org.primefaces.component.column.Column;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer;

public class ExtendedDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeColumnHeader(FacesContext context, DataTable table, UIColumn column) throws IOException {
        table.pushComponentToEL(context, (Column) column);

        try {
            super.encodeColumnHeader(context, table, column);
        }
        finally {
            table.popComponentFromEL(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void encodeCell(FacesContext context, DataTable table, UIColumn column, String clientId, boolean selected) throws IOException {
        table.pushComponentToEL(context, (Column) column);

        try {
            super.encodeCell(context, table, column, clientId, selected);
        }
        finally {
            table.popComponentFromEL(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void encodeColumnFooter(FacesContext context, DataTable table, UIColumn column) throws IOException {
        table.pushComponentToEL(context, (Column) column);

        try {
            super.encodeColumnFooter(context, table, column);
        }
        finally {
            table.popComponentFromEL(context);
        }
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <description>Overrides the PrimeFaces table renderer with improved #{component} support.</description>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.stackoverflow.q25464066.ExtendedDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```